# View added in ViewGroup is not displayed

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a view in a viewGroup (without xml) but can't make the view appear. I can't figure out what I'm missing...please help, I've been looking all the web for hours now.
Here is my code (the Background class extends ViewGroup) :

```
public void setupBackground()
{
    this.backgroundView = new Background(activity);     

    View bgGround = new View(activity);
    bgGround.setX(100);
    bgGround.setY(200);
    bgGround.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    bgGround.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mario_ground);
    this.backgroundView.addView(bgGround, 100,100);

    this.activity.addContentView(backgroundView, new LayoutParams(bgWidth,bgHeight));       
}
```

Comment: and your `bgGround` instance is the one that isn't appearing, right? What kind of `LayoutParams` are you using? Are you certain that `bgWidth` and `bgHeight` hold the right values?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's it, bgGround doesn't appear. bgWidth and bgHeight are ok (1024 and 552). I use this kind of LayoutParams LayoutParams(int width, int height). When I try adding bgGround on the activity with addContentView it works, but i want it to be added to the backgroundView.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it. ViewGroup is not enough for drawing content, I had to extend RelativeLayout (or another kind of layout) instead. 
What made me loose lot of time is that I had overrid onLayout method while still in ViewGroup and then changed to RelativeLayout, so the onLayout for RelativeLayout wasn't calling super.onLayout.

Thanks anyway, and sorry for my poor english :)